# How can I get my physically based sky to be blue all the way down?

Tags: unity, rendering, lighting, hdrp

I'm rendering with a physically based sky. I want to get a very simple light blue background but below the horizon the sky becomes grey/brown. How can I get it so that the sky is blue all the way down? As if the edge of the city was the edge of the world.

I also want to make the blue sky brighter, especially at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: What is a "physically based sky"? If you mean you're modelling Raleigh scattering... I have no idea what to tell you.

Comment: @Almo [It's a feature of the High-Definition Render Pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.1/manual/Override-Physically-Based-Sky.html)

Comment: This is just a guess, but looking at the `Properties` menu from the link above, there's a `Ground Color` field - have you experimented with changing that color?

Comment: The `Ground Tint` option does seem to be the right fix